# Are there licensing issues in modifying an existing public AMI and making the modified version public?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

We'd like to take an existing Linux base AMI, install our software on it, and make the modified AMI available publicly. What are the licensing implications of doing this? Our software is an open source bioinformatics tool, but does not use a GPL compatible license. I haven't been able to find any discussion of this in the Amazon documentation. They explain how to build a customized AMI from a public AMI, but no mention is made of any IP or licensing issues.

My concern is that the modified AMI would be a derived work, which I think would obligate us to license our software under a GPL compatible license.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any GPL code actually in your software, including it in the AMI would only require you to release your software under GPL if it was part of the terms specific to the AMI.

The part I am unsure about is if you would be required to supply the source code to all of the GPL software in the AMI, hopefully someone else can clarify this for you. The safest option would be to just release a package for the distribution and possibly a shell script to automatically install it and any necessary repositories.